# Carbon Time Difference of Local Time and Server Time

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-4, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 4 and trying to calculate the difference of the Time on Server and the Time Save in Database in hours. Here is the code:

Time on Server=timeNowOnServer   // 2016-02-03 19:05:43
Time saved in Database = setTime // 18:00:00

```
        $timeNowOnServer = null;
        $setTime = null;

        $timeZone = $company->time_zone;
        $company->save();

        // My Time
        $hour = substr($company->emp_auto_logout_time, 0, 2);
        $setTime = Carbon::createFromTime($hour);

        // Server Time Same as Mine
        $timeNowOnServer = Carbon::now();
        $timeNowOnServerSameAsMine = $timeNowOnServer->setTimezone($timeZone);

        // Time Differnce Between SetTime and TimeOnServerSameAsMine
        $timeDiff = $setTime->diffInHours($timeNowOnServerSameAsMine, $abs = false);
```

If `Server Time` is 14:00:00 for example and `Set Time` is 19:00:00. My time zone is `GMT +5 Pakistan`.

What I'm doing is, adding setting `Server Time` according to user time by giving `time zone` in the 3rd last line of the above given code.

When I use `diffInHour` it instead of giving me 0 it gives me -5 or 5. It means it's useing `UTC (Server Time)` and that's why give wrong difference in hours.

Can someone please let me know where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to diff time in different time zones. A time difference (interval) is an absolute value, it doesn't depend on time zone. One second is always one second, be it `UTC` or `Europe/Moscow`.

Try without time zone (to be correct - using default server's time zone)

```
$timeDiff = $setTime->diffInHours($timeNowOnServer, $abs = false);
```

Always calc intervals using timestamps or the same time zone (doesn't matter exactly which one) for both DT values.

Comment: How to get timestamps from a carbon object?

Comment: @MKJ `$carbonObject->timestamp`. Did my example help?

Comment: yes, it did help me. Thanks.
In fact I have to get Now time of server, and Set time from DB, then convert Server Time according the timezone of user local time, I just need hours. Then compare if Server Hours > Set Hour (Db saved time hour) and perform action if true. Is it right approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your task right. If it's about starting something on time (kind of schedule) then you have to format date and time in a time zone where action has to be performed. And then compare dt **representation**, not absolute diff.